# .split().join() returning more characters than originally present

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am seeing weird behavior when splitting a string with a lookahead with a capture group.

I sometimes get more characters than in the original string. I would not think that possible.

**Javascript** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g44yb/1/)

```
'ab'.split(/(?=b)/).join('');
'ab'.split(/(?=(?:b))/).join('');
'ab'.split(/(?=(b))/).join('');

'ab'
'ab'
'abb'
```

Other lanaguages:

**Java/Scala**

```
"ab".split("(?=b)").mkString
"ab".split("(?=(?:b))").mkString
"ab".split("(?=(b))").mkString

"ab"
"ab"
"ab"
```

**PHP**

```
implode(preg_split('/(?=b)/', 'ab'));
implode(preg_split('/(?=(?:b))/', 'ab'));
implode(preg_split('/(?=(b))/', 'ab'));

'ab'
'ab'
'ab'
```

---

Why does Javascript wind up with more characters than the original string for the third regex? I have reproduced this with Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE 11.

---

**EDIT**:

It appears Ruby does the same thing:

```
'ab'.split(%r{(?=b)}).join
'ab'.split(%r{(?=(?:b))}).join
'ab'.split(%r{(?=(b))}).join

'ab'
'ab'
'abb'
```

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If `separator` is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time `separator` is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

So when you have a capturing group, even in a lookahead, like this:

```
'ab'.split(/(?=(b))/)
```

The result will include `a` and `b`, the two portions of the string before and after the position which matched the lookahead, but it will also include the portion of the string which matched the group inside the lookahead, `b`.

However, the MDN article goes on to point out:

> However, not all browsers support this capability.

So I wouldn't necessarily expect this behavior to be consistent across all browsers.

Comment: "However, not all browsers support this capability." Are those non-standards compliant browsers?

Comment: @PaulDraper The precise algorithm is defined in [section 15.5.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14) of the  ECMAScript specification.

Comment: @PaulDraper The way I read the spec, yes this is standards-compliant behavior, and any deviation from this would not be standards compliant. Lookahead assertions can contain 'capturing parentheses' according to [section 15.10.2.8 Note 2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.8), so the the captured substring should be included in the result array even if it appears in a lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

It is because javascript put automatically capture group in split result.